# Convert html file in node.js to pdf and write the same in disk

Tags: node.js, npm, pdf-conversion

In my application I have one html template which brings dynamic data from DB. I need to convert that html file(template) to PDF. Is there any package to convert the raw html to PDF in node.js? I go through with pdfcrowd and livedocx. Both using some webservices for conversion which does not suits for my specification. please suggest some package for converting HTML to PDF in local machine..?

Answer (score -1):

Go through [this](https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf) link..

Here u can convert HTML file to PDF or HTML content to PDF

`import NDHTMLtoPDF.h` and `NDHTMLtoPDF.m` from above source link

pass HTML file path to generate PDF here..

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:HTMLPath];
```

Converting HTML to PDF

```
self.PDFCreator = [NDHTMLtoPDF createPDFWithURL:targetURL
                                     pathForPDF:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Documents/Sample.pdf"] stringByExpandingTildeInPath]
                                       delegate:self
                                       pageSize:kPaperSizeA4
                                        margins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 5, 90, 5)];
```

pass HTML Content to generate PDF here..

```
NSString *str_PDFName_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Documents/Sample.pdf"];
self.PDFCreator = [NDHTMLtoPDF createPDFWithHTML:str_HTML pathForPDF:[str_PDFName_path stringByExpandingTildeInPath] delegate:self pageSize:kPaperSizeA4 margins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 5, 90, 5)];
```

Comment: It seems to for some other app. i need it in node.

Comment: what is mean by node? can u post the code what ur doing exactly?